# Syntax error on token ".", super expected after this token

Tags: java, android

like previously I am making an app and there's one error (finally) in that.

```
button1.setOnClickListener(
    new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View_v) {
            Email = edittext1.getText().toString();
            Password = edittext1.getText().toString();
            if (!((Email.trim().length() == 0) && (Password.trim().length() == 0 ))) {
                final ProgressDialog pg = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this); 
                pg.setCancelable(false); 
                pg.setMessage("loading...");
                pg.show();
```

Now it makes another error:

```
ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this); 
pg.setCancelable(false); 
pg.setMessage("loading..."); pg.show();
                             ˆ
Syntax error on token ".", super expected after this token
```

Comment: Are you sure this is the whole code? It seems that there's no error in it, except for the semi colon on `Password = ediittext1.getText().toString()`

Comment: This is also not possible: `public void onClick(View_v) {`

Answer (score 1):

- Remove **`1`** from `pg.show();`

use **`pg.show();`** instead of **`pg.show(1);`**

```
final ProgressDialog pg = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this); 
                pg.setCancelable(false); 
                pg.setMessage("loading...");
                pg.show();
```

- also  add **`;`** after `Password = ediittext1.getText().toString();`

like below code

```
 Password = ediittext1.getText().toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

> Syntax error on token ".", super expected after this token

- Use **`show()`** end of Dialog. Don't **`show(n)`**

Code

```
final ProgressDialog pg = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this); 
                pg.setCancelable(false); 
                pg.setMessage("loading...");
                pg.show();
```

**EDIT**

Add **`;`**

```
 Password = ediittext1.getText().toString();
```